# Unity3d GUI modal window

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a main script that is attached to the "world" (root) object on the scene and is responsible for global things such as global key events, debugging, etc...

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.color = Color.red;
    GUI.depth = 220;
    windowRect0 = GUI.ModalWindow(0, windowRect0, DoMyWindow, "Red Window");
}
void DoMyWindow(int windowID)
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 20, 100, 20), "Hello World"))
    {
        print("Got a click in window with color " + GUI.color);
        Event.current.Use();
    }else
    {
        Event.current.Use();
    }
    GUI.DragWindow(new Rect(0, 0, 10000, 10000));
}
```

I also have multiple objects dynamically generated on the screen (chess squares), each has a script that highlights itself when mouse hovers over and each pops detailed info (a prefab) when mouse clicks over it:

```
public class ChessTileHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler{

...
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
.. highlight object...
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
... return to normal
    }
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
... pop details...
    }

}
```

The idea is the root object would pop the little debugging modal window on a particular key combination. It does pop the window, but it is not modal, when I click on the button from the GUI debug window, the chess square behind it reacts properly with a click event, it also reacts with a hover event when i hover over the GUI elements.

my question is, how do I create a truly modal window that would "eat" any mouse click on it (and preferably any mouse click outside it too) until I disable the GUI element?

Comment: My primary recommendation here is to use the new Unity UI, rather than the legacy `GUI` methods. This will allow you to use the Event System to differentiate between whether the pointer is directly over top of a GameObject, or if something is in the way (among the countless other benefits of using the new UI).

Comment: I was having some issues using event system where it would behave the same way - events always happening for anything behind the cursor. I managed to create a truly modal window by having a transparent image cover the whole screen, but i'm still not fully understanding the whole process. I feel like it's a 'dirty' solution. Am I right or is that actually a good solution?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with taking the transparent image approach - a lot of modals in web design actually function this way, by putting a transparent layer over the rest of the page to catch click events (sometimes graying out the page to signify that interactivity is disabled).

Comment: I had a weird effect with transparent image approach, where when cursor is outside the screen, but is landing on the chess tile which is partially outside the screen and partially displayed on the screen, that chess tile would still highlight. I am not sure why its happening and because of that I was hoping for a simple modal solution, something that doesn't involve a 'hack' with a transparent image. I mean, in VB6 it was so easy to pop a modal window that would behave like a modal window without using images or other hacks.